# Qt Quick: Is there any way to make text selectable?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using QT 5.14, but cannot find they way to make `Text` component selectable..
Is there any way to do it?

What I need is to be able to select multiple blocks of texts (not within single text block only, but like in regular html page).

I tired with read only `TextEdit`, I can select only  inside `TextEdit`, but not texts of multiple instances..

For context: I want to try to implement simple chat app with qt, and make chat messages selectable (like for example in Slack).

For chat history I'm thinking to use `ListView` with custom components which include `Text` and other components (Image, links, etc).

P.S: I don't want to use WebView or WebEngine

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to select multiple `TextEdit` objects or would like to select text in multiple `TextEdit` components?

Comment: Ideally I want to avoid TextEdit, just use Text... Regarding TextEdit: select texts in multiple TextEdit components